# Pass dynamic id to be reused throughout function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a group of `<p>` elements with unique id's (#one-context, #two-context, #three-context). I'd like to reveal a corresponding div element (starts with "scale-" and ends with either "one", "two" or "three") when hovered over each `<p>` element.

Is it possible to write code, simple & short, so when each element is hovered, the wildcard(?) "one" "two" or "three" of the `p` element gets stored as it iterates through the group? Here is where I'm currently at:

```
$("p[id$='-context']").mouseover(function() {
  $("div[id^='scale']").addClass("active-badge");
}).mouseout(function() {
  $("div[id^='scale-']").removeClass("active-badge");
});


<div id="scale-one">1</div>
<div id="scale-two">2</div>
<div id="scale-three">3</div>

<p id="one-context">Context 1</p>
<p id="two-context">Context 2</p>
<p id="three-context">Context 3</p>
```

So, it's essentially saving the values of "one", "two" and "three".

Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example. Inside the `mouseover` function `this` is a hovered node. You get it's id, cut off the `"-context"` part and get the selector like `"div[id='scale-one']"`

```js
$("p[id$='-context']").mouseover(function() {
  $("div[id='scale-" + $(this).attr("id").replace("-context", "") + "']")
    .addClass("active-badge");
}).mouseout(function() {
  $("div[id='scale-" + $(this).attr("id").replace("-context", "") + "']")
    .removeClass("active-badge");
});
```

```css
.active-badge {
    color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="scale-one">1</div>
<div id="scale-two">2</div>
<div id="scale-three">3</div>

<p id="one-context">Context 1</p>
<p id="two-context">Context 2</p>
<p id="three-context">Context 3</p>
```

Comment: That's a certified beauty! Thank you so much. It works.

Comment: @RandyDaniel by the way, if you think I've answered your question, please accept my answer. Thank you